# Show album of Facebook pictures in a lightbox on own website

Tags: jquery, facebook

so I was trying to show an album from my facebook fanpage on my website.
I used this code and managed to get the pictures (formatted with css) on my website, 
but installing a lightbox to show the full size images won't work. Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance!

code:

```
HEAD
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //fbAlbum Script courtesy of zach@lysobey.com | http://zach.lysobey.com/projects/fbalbum
    (function($){$.fn.fbAlbum=function(f){var g=this;var h={'albumID':10150302289698306,'limit':100,'ul':'album','callback':'','title':true};if(f){$.extend(h,f)}var i="https://graph.facebook.com/"+h.albumID+"/photos?limit="+h.limit+"&callback=?";$.getJSON(i,function(a){var b=[];for(var c in a){for(var d in a[c]){val2=a[c][d];if(typeof(val2.source)!="undefined"){var e="";if(h.title&&val2.name){e=val2.name}b.push('<li><a href="'+val2.source+'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="'+e+'"><img src="'+val2.picture+'" width="72" height="72"   /></a></li>')}}};$('<ul />',{'class':h.ulClass,html:b.join('')}).appendTo(g);if(h.callback){h.callback()}});return this}})(jQuery);    
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#gallery').fbAlbum({
            'albumID':XXX 
        }); 
    });
    </script>

BODY
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

PS: I was trying to use this jQuery lightbox: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this post.  I'm the author of the FBalbum plugin you're using. There is actually a 'callback' option you can pass the fbAlbum function, where you should put the script to initialize the lightbox.

[See this example page(with fancybox plugin)](http://zach.lysobey.com/files/demo_fancybox)

Comment: also feel free to email me if you're still stuck - I'm more than happy to help!